# is it possible to use a single stored procedure for search to all different tables?

Tags: sql-server

```
create procedure search
@table varchar(50),@column varchar(50),@searchkey varchar(20)
as
select @column from @table where @column like '%@searchkey%'
```

is that possible? if not please do suggest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Go with Dynamic coding

```
create procedure search
@table varchar(50),@column varchar(50),@searchkey varchar(20)
as
BEGIN
    DECLARE  @QRY VARCHAR(MAX)='select '+@column+' from '+@table+' 
    where '+@column+' like %'+@searchkey+'%';
    EXEC (@QRY);

END
```

Comment: I would use an full text query with replacing tags instead to build `@QRY : @QRY = 'SELECT #COL1# FROM #TABLE# WHERE #COL1# LIKE ''%#KEY#''';` folowed by `@QRY = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@QRY,'#COL1#',@Column),'#TABLE#',@Table),'#KEY#',@searchkey)`

Comment: Its not a SQL Server syntax.. OP need it in SQL Server @clementakis

Comment: Sorry for the missing SET ... `SET @QRY = 'SELECT #COL1# FROM #TABLE# WHERE #COL1# LIKE ''%#KEY#'''`
folowed by `SET @QRY = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@QRY,'#COL1#',@Column),'#TABLE#',@Table),'#KEY#',@searckey)`